# How do i make the image which i draw in canvas as linkable

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, anchor

In my pdfjs I am creating hot spot so am adding image on mouse click position,
Next I have to give link to that image , So if i click that image it should redirect me to the particular link

```
  base_image = new Image();
   base_image.src = '/images/dot.png';
   base_image.draggable="true"
   console.log(base_image)
   var x = e.offsetX - base_image.width/2;
  var y = e.offsetY - base_image.height/2;
  ctx.drawImage(base_image, x, y);
```

How can I able to do this?

Comment: You'll have to find the mouse position and check if it's over the image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, During click itself i have found the mouse position  how can i able to add link for that image

Comment: You have to store the position and size of image. Then every time you click on canvas you check if mouse position is inside - if so, trigger the link.

Comment: for each image it will be different link, it also draggable and resizeable

Comment: You'll probably be better off by using HTML element over canvas, so you don't have to reimplement all of that.

Comment: Ok thank you its get appending but not able to click

Comment: Wrap the image in `<a href="url">`.

Comment: ya added .. But not able to click . Do u have any idea to find position in pdf.js